How to make button screen responsive?
I'm new to coding and working on a personal project. I'm trying to make the website responsive, but when I change size of screen, the buttons are fixed to screen and not the image, therefore they are not connected anymore (please see screenshot) Hope someone can help me :)
(https://i.sstatic.net/EDlqAcEZ.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/OhoBZG18.png)
I added the position of the buttons this way
    <Button
        variant="light"
        style={{
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: "-3%", 
        right: "43%",
        }}>
    <Button/>


can you share more information about the Button component, are you using some framework, react, solid? Does it take other props?
